# SQL Server - How to make partially duplicate rows inherit values from original row

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, append, updates

In order to link records across datasets I first deleted the records down to non-duplicates based on key linking variables (partitioning over names, dob, sex etc. and deleting where row_number > 1). After the linking was done I'm left with a new variable "unique_id" however this will only be attributed to the original record (since I removed the partial duplicates). I now want to reattach this "unique_id" back to all of the partial duplicates. How could I go about doing this? Is there perhaps a better method I could have used from the start?

Data currently looks like this:

```
row_number unique_id id      first_name last_name activity_date
1          10        2       Davy       Jones     1726-11-25
2          --        12      Davy       Jones     1751-02-11
3          --        43      Davy       Jones     1811-06-15
1          100       12114   John       Smith     2018-06-01
2          --        123123  John       Smith     2022-07-05
1          90        2591    Mary       Sue       2013-05-18
```

And I want the "unique_id" to inherit the originals like this:

```
row_number unique_id id      first_name last_name activity_date
1          10        2       Davy       Jones     1726-11-25
2          10        12      Davy       Jones     1751-02-11
3          10        43      Davy       Jones     1811-06-15
1          100       12114   John       Smith     2018-06-01
2          100       123123  John       Smith     2022-07-05
1          90        2591    Mary       Sue       2013-05-18
```

Code to produce this table is as follows:

```
create table #test (
    unique_id int,
    id int,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    activity_date date
)

insert into #test 
values (100, 12114, 'John', 'Smith', '2018-06-01')

insert into #test (id, first_name, last_name, activity_date)
values (123123, 'John', 'Smith', '2022-07-05')

insert into #test
values (90, 2591, 'Mary', 'Sue', '2013-05-18')

insert into #test
values (10, 2, 'Davy', 'Jones', '1726-11-25')

insert into #test (id, first_name, last_name, activity_date)
values (12, 'Davy', 'Jones', '1751-02-11')

insert into #test (id, first_name, last_name, activity_date)
values (43, 'Davy', 'Jones', '1811-06-15')

select 
row_number() over (partition by first_name, last_name order by first_name, last_name) as row_number
,unique_id, id, first_name, last_name, activity_date
from #test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with Dups as(
    select 
    row_number() over (partition by first_name, last_name order by first_name, last_name) as dup_number,
    -- dense_rank() over (order by first_name, last_name) as DuplicateGroupNumber, -- this allows you to see groups
    max(unique_id) over (partition by first_name, last_name) as GroupUniqueID,
    unique_id, id, first_name, last_name, activity_date
    from #test
)
update a
set unique_id = GroupUniqueID
from #test as a
    inner join Dups as b on a.id = b.id

select * from #test
```

Result

```
unique_id   id          first_name  
----------- ----------- ------------
100         12114       John        
100         123123      John        
90          2591        Mary        
10          2           Davy        
10          12          Davy        
10          43          Davy
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple method -- assuming one value per `first_name`/`last_name` pair -- is to use window functions:

```
select t.*, max(unique_id) over (partition by first_name, last_name) as new_unique_id
from #test t;
```

This can be put into an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(unique_id) over (partition by first_name, last_name) as new_unique_id
      from #test t
     )
update toupdate
    set unique_id = new_unique_id;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/MGR59290) illustrating the syntax.

Comment: What version of SQL is this?

Comment: @Alex . . . This is SQL Server syntax -- that is the tag on the question.

Comment: I tried running your code on SQL 2014 and it is complaining about `update toupdate`.

Comment: @Alex . . . I was updating the wrong field, but the code works.  I added a rextester so you can see the syntax working.

Comment: Just to aid my understanding - You didn't need to specify the `FROM #test ... INNER JOIN Dups` after the update statement like Alex's answer since you have already specified the `FROM #test` inside the `WITH` function and you are directly updating from this (whereas Alex updated from #test instead of the WITH function initially created)?

Comment: @Maharero . . . My answer uses an updatable CTE.  It references one table so no `join` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should join a subset of the records that has the linking id with the records that don't have the linking id using whatever fields you think appropriate and then update the id in the unlinked set from the id in the linked set.